# String.Match() without RegEX

Tags: javascript

In the following snippet, I'm unsure how the RegEx is assigned to match(), is a RegEx always needed?:

----------Match------------

```
case 'remove':
var rep=o.className.match(' '+c1)?' '+c1:c1;
o.className=o.className.replace(rep,'');
break;
```

------Full--Code--------------

```
function cssjs(a,o,c1,c2){
switch (a){
case 'swap':
if(!domtab.cssjs('check',o,c1)){
o.className.replace(c2,c1)
}else{
o.className.replace(c1,c2);
}
break;
case 'add':
if(!domtab.cssjs('check',o,c1)){
o.className+=o.className?' '+c1:c1;
}
break;
case 'remove':
var rep=o.className.match(' '+c1)?' '+c1:c1;
o.className=o.className.replace(rep,'');
break;
case 'check':
var found=false;
var temparray=o.className.split(' ');
for(var i=0;i<temparray.length;i++){
if(temparray[i]==c1){found=true;}
}
```

Comment: Which regexp are you talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing a string into `match` is the same as passing the result of `new RegExp(s)` into it (where `s` is the string). E.g., these do exactly the same thing:

```
a = str.match("foo");
a = str.match(new RegExp("foo"));
```

From [the standard](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.10):

> 1. If `Type(regexp)` is `Object` and the value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of regexp is "RegExp", then let `rx` be `regexp`;
> 2. Else, let `rx` be a new `RegExp` object created as if by the expression `new RegExp( regexp)` where `RegExp` is the standard built-in constructor with that name.

Comment: So many thanks for the reply and link. Just the reference needed.